# css selector on the body section

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to add CSS selector inside the body section? Here is my code for example (but it doesn't work):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style= "a[target=_blank] {background-color: yellow;}"> **css selector on this section
  <a href="http://test.com">test</a>
  <a href="http://test1.com" target="_blank">test1</a>
  <a href="http://test2.com" target="_top">test2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/) says it is not possible. Use [`<style>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) tag instead to define specific CSS rules for your page.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use selectors inside inline style. the inline style will effect only on element that style tag located in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine when using css in a style sheet.

As far as I know inline styles only effect the element the style is on and so cannot be used to change another.

```css
a[target=_blank] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <a href="http://test.com">test</a>
  <a href="http://test1.com" target="_blank">test1</a>
  <a href="http://test2.com" target="_top">test2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```